# SqLite Database error inside asynctask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I run some DB stuff inside an asynctask that runs inside a runnable via handler.postdelayed(r, 30000). It gets repeated (as you can see, every 30 seconds).

Sometimes, not everytime, my app is crashing. Below is the logcat.

```
09-24 18:28:52.813: W/dalvikvm(6194): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40daf1f8)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.myApp/databases/mydb.db (conn# 0) already closed
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2100)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:418)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:405)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:79)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:164)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:156)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at com.myApp.DbAllHelper.dbMethod1(DbAllHelper.java:273)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at com.myApp.DbAllHelper.dbMethod2(DbAllHelper.java:582)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at com.myApp.MainActivity$checkToInternetOnly.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:278)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at com.myApp.MainActivity$checkToInternetOnly.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get somewhere along the logcat an `IllegalStateException` because the database is already closed. Make sure your background tasks are canceled before you close the database, which is done latest in `onDestroy` of your Activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
09-24 18:28:52.823: E/AndroidRuntime(6194): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.myApp/databases/mydb.db (conn# 0) already closed
```

Are you sure you did not close a Cursor by accident before usage. That or is the asynctask by any chance started twice at some point?

Whatever the reason is, it seems the code at some point is trying to access a closed Cursor.